# How to process memory spaces saved in a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've saved in a pointer an address of a word saved in a char list. I'm using strtok function to get the words delimited by the keywords I've set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        unsigned int i, z;
        char sir[256];
        cin.getline(sir, 256);
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(sir); ++i){
                char * p = strtok(sir, " ,.");
                while(p != nullptr) {
                        // here i want to process the word.
                        p = strtok(sir, " ,.");
                }
        }

return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is to process the words like that:
Let's assume the word "StackOverflow", i want to go from the first letter which is "S" to the last letter which is "w". How can i do that?

Thank you very much, I hope it's clear what I'm asking.

Comment: Warning: `strtok` is destructive, when it finds a delimiter it replaces it with a nul character to give you a nice null terminated string. This completely <expletive deleted>s up  `strlen(sir)`

Comment: `p = strtok(sir, " ,.");` will start at the beginning of `sir`, so inside `while(p != nullptr)`, `p` will never change. It'll always point to the first token in the string. You want `p = strtok(nullptr, " ,.");` inside the loop to pick up where `strtok` left off.

Comment: But that makes an utter hash of the `for(i = 0; i < strlen(sir); ++i)` loop. You need to stop writing code and draw up a better plan. I mean literally draw. Make a flowchart. Work through the flowchart with pen and paper and a few sample input strings to debug the flowchart. Once the logic is sound, you can write code. If you code without a plan, you wind up on the road to nowhere.

Comment: Also make sure you've read documentation for the library functions you are using. [Good documentation for `std::strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) outlines the issues raised in the first two comments, making them easy to avoid.

Comment: Worth adding to the question whether or not you have to use `strtok`. Someone may be able to offer a solution that uses a more "native" C++ solution that doesn't fall back on older C-style character array manipulating functions. Though I'll admit C++ doesn't offer a multi-delimiter parser right out of the box.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using C-strings in C++? we have std::string you know?

Comment: And now that I've tried answering the question, I'm not 100% certain what you want out. Please add a moderately complex input string that contains multiple tokens and a couple of the delimiters and the expected output for the input string.

Comment: I recommend using `std::string` and `std::getline` with delimiter.  A lot easier than destroying character arrays with `strtok`.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the input to a static value; but just switch that out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int i, z;
    char sir[256] = "Thisissome ,.StackOverflow ,.sampletext";
    //cin.getline(sir, 256);
    char * p = strtok(sir, " ,.");
    std::string word("StackOverflow");
    do
    {
        printf ("%s\n",p);
        std::string test(p);
        if (word.compare(test) == 0)
        {
            printf("--> Found it!\n");
        }               
        p = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    } while(p != nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

strtok splits a string into a series of tokens. It shouldn't be successively called using the original character array to parse based on a delimiter. (i.e. the for(...) strtok(...) in OP).

The initial call expects a c-string for argument; and successful calls expects a nullptr. One each successive call; the next value will be returned from the c-string after the delimiter.

Once a null character is found; the function call will always return nullptr ( when nullptr is the first argument).

Since the solution is already using C++, this solution uses a std::string to show how each sequence of words will appear; and can be compared against a token word.

The value returned to p is still just a char*, so the OP can decide how to use the value returned by strtok. The example is intended to simply show to return delimited words using strtok; and a simple solution for seeing if that word is "StackOverflow"

Comment: What doe this mean? Please improve you answer. Don't just throw some code you think you fixed.

Comment: @user4581301 Actually the starting location will always be the first character not contained in the limiters, and then scans until it finds the first character in the delimiters. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: You are correct. I got my parsers mixed up. Should have taken my own advice and checked the documentation before spouting off.